# URLEncoder limits the response of the server

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming

I have the following problem..

when I hardcoded a url query which is like

example :

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gslimit=5&gsradius=10000&gscoord=51.4451254|5.4731413&format=json

(check the link in your browser)

and I make the request to the server, I get the whole response in a string..

However when I make it dynamically I have to pass the "|" character, in URLEncoder.encode("|", "UTF-8") this format...

In that case, the response is only one element of what I want..

Is it something that it is missing to me?

Thanks in advance

```
protected String doInBackground(String... query) {


        String response = "";
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpGet = null;

        // try {
        HttpResponse execute = null;
        try {
            //String searchTerm  = URLEncoder.encode(query[0], "UTF-8");
            httpGet = new HttpGet(query[0]);
            execute = client.execute(httpGet);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStream content = null;
        try {
            content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                content));
        String s = "";
        try {
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;

    }
```

The above part is my code.. the input query[0] is the url that I am requesting and it is similar to the link that I posted in the beginning.

If I hardcoded the url (set directly the the link), I have the response. My response is a string in json format. (for now I let it string)

If I make the query dynamically, for example like:

```
gsQuery =  mainPage  + "&gsradius=" + radius + "&gscoord=" + latitude + URLEncoder.encode("|", "UTF-8") + longtitude +"&format=json";
```

(encoded only the "|" character) it returns only the first element of my response.

Comment: What's the problem? Is the output not as expected? What is it?

Comment: You have to URLEncode all argument names and values, not just individual characters. Your question is unanswerable without the code concerned.

Comment: ok I will share more ...

Comment: So, I repeat, you're doing it wrong. What happens when you do it right?

Comment: ok, when I am doing it correctly, after the call of the execute = client.execute(httpGet); Then I have a stuck on the  RunWorker in the w.unlock(); // allow interrupts. It is also a android app